# Using Xcode's preprocessing to set info.plist keys and values

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to find a way to conditionally enable a launch storyboard, depending on the build configuration.

I have all xcconfig and related build configurations set up, I've configured `INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=YES` and properly formatted `INFOPLIST_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.

The app runs as expected. For example, this info.plist setting for my app does what is expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        … various plist settings

        #if USE_LAUNCH_STORYBOARD
        <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
        <string>Launch</string>
        #endif
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Setting USE_LAUNCH_STORYBOARD to `YES` or `NO` will turn the launch storyboard on or off, falling back to the preconfigured launch images.

However, this isn't a valid XML format and two things break. First, Xcode won't open the info.plist as a property list, only as source code. Second, tests won't launch. An error of "Could not determine bundle identifier for [test target] test host…" is raise before compilation begins.

Has anybody successfully used info.plist preprocessing to configure out whole key/value pairs? I have a hacky solution that puts the `#if USE_LAUNCH_STORYBOARD` / `#endif` in some throwaway `<string>` tags to create a valid XML format but, for whatever reason, the `#if` fails to process the `USE_LAUNCH_STORYBOARD` value and always launches with a storyboard. I've tried using CDATA wrappers in various incarnations with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing similar issues. What is the difference between enabling the preprocessor and just using plain xcconfig files?

Comment: I could not find a way to do this exclusively in the plist. I ended up writing a build script that used plistbuddy to modify the contents of the plist. Not a beautiful solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is quite simple. For each client project I made a group with LaunchScreen named to correspond to the client. I included it and all its resources for each client in the target. Next, since each client has its own info.plist I point to these specific info.plist's by setting this in the build settings. Since each of the plist files refers to a specificly named launchscreen it just works. What I found was that you have to pull all assets used in the launchscreen into the group and add them to the target. Also, vector pdf files do not seem to work properly.